# PHP namespace and global autoload single file

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

This is an experiment with PHP namespaces / autoload in a single file.

```
namespace trust;

class trust_network{        
    public function __construct(){      
        print "SUP";
    }
}

namespace trust2;

$trust = new \trust\trust_network(); $do = new \test();

function __autoload($class){
    require($class.".php");     
    print $class;
}
```

So under namespace trust2, I'm calling "\test" - aka I'd like to autoload that class from an external file on a global base.  What I wrote does not work.  I know that I've got __autoload under a namespace, but how do I declare that on a global basis?  Can't include before namespace declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple namespaces in one file you should use the curly bracket syntax:

```
namespace n1 {
...
}
namespace n2 {
...
}
namespace {
...
}
```

In the last block you can declare functions in the global namespace. Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php

Comment: This does work actually, is there a way to do it with out curling it?

Comment: The documentation on PHP says that the syntax without braces "is not recommended for combining namespaces into a single file. Instead it is recommended to use the alternate bracketed syntax."

Comment: The docs also state that for global namespace only bracket syntax is supported

Answer (score 2):

Autoload is usually so that you can put one class per file. Therefore, you should have the following layout

**/index.php**

```
function __autoload($class){
    // You may need to convert backslashes in $class to forward slashes 
    // and strip the first slash, we'll leave the
    require($class.".php");
    // debug-only:  print $class;
}
// Calling new here triggers __autoload to be called
$trust = new \trust\trust_network();
$do = new \test();
```

**/trust/trust_network.php**

```
namespace trust;

class trust_network{        
    public function __construct(){      
        print "TRUST_NETWORK";
    }
}
```

**/test.php**

```
class test() {
    public function __construct(){      
        print "TEST";
    }
}
```

Note that you should use [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead since it allows multiple systems to hook in their own autoload behavior. As of PHP 5.3, you can do the following

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require($class.".php");
});
```

Comment: Juan, this is correct, but the goal here is to attempt this in a single document.

Comment: Why not.  Not that this will be used in the real world, but to push PHP to its limits.

Comment: @MichaelMikhjian So the real problem is that you want some code to be namespaced and some code not to be namespaced? Then fab has the solution.

Comment: Exactly.  Your answer is correct from a split file basis, but the subject here is single file.  Really appreciate you going through though!